# Where should I check if the user session is still active?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, react-router

I am having a problem while checking firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged() to know if there is an active session so the user doesnt have to log in multiple times. The session check works properly, but it breaks my Router.

I implemented it in App.js with the following code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import { auth } from './config/Firebase';
import { isUserLoggedIn } from './actions/Authentication';
import Log from './utils/Log';
import Navigation from './components/Navigation/Navigation';
import HomePage from './components/HomePage/HomePage';
import LoginPage from './components/LoginPage/LoginPage';

class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        loading: true
    };

    componentWillMount = () => {
        Log.info('Will mount', 'App.js');
        const listener = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            if (user) {
                this.props.isUserLoggedIn(user);
                Log.info(user, 'App.js. User is set: ');
                this.setState({ loading: false });
                listener();
            } else {
                this.props.isUserLoggedIn({});
                Log.info('User was deleted', 'App.js');
                this.setState({ loading: false });
                listener();
            }
        });
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.loading === true ? 
                    <h1>Loading</h1> 
                : 
                    <div>
                        <Navigation />
                        <div className="container">
                            <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage} />
                            <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />   
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        ) 
    }
}

App.propTypes = {
    isUserLoggedIn: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default connect(null, { isUserLoggedIn })(App);
```

My dirty code of ReactDom.render is the following:

```
const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)));

ReactDOM.render(
    <IntlProvider locale={language} messages={messages[language]}>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <App />
            </BrowserRouter>
        </Provider>
    </IntlProvider>, document.getElementById('root')
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

isUserLoggedIn is an action that will dispatch the current user if there is a session active:

```
import { auth } from '../config/Firebase';

export const USER_LOGGED_IN = 'USER_LOGGED_IN';
export const SET_CURRENT_USER = 'SET_CURRENT_USER';

export const userLoggedIn = user => ({
    type: USER_LOGGED_IN,
    user
});
export const setCurrentUser = user => ({
    type: SET_CURRENT_USER,
    user
});

export const login = credentials => dispatch =>
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(credentials.email, credentials.password)
    .then(user => dispatch(userLoggedIn(user.user)));

export const isUserLoggedIn = (user) => dispatch =>
    dispatch(setCurrentUser(user));
```

I want the app to be in a "loading" state until the "user" object is set in the redux store, which I process when App.js is being mounted. This works properly, however, if I connect { isUserLoggedIn } to App.js, the Links that call to different Routes just doesn't work. If I manually change the url, it works fine, however, if I click a button that Links me to other component, the url changes but it doesn't show me the component. As soon as I remove the connect line from App.js, the Links start working again.

It is clear this is not the way to check the session as it breaks the Routes, so, where should I be checking it if it is not App.js?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I ended up solving it.

I moved BrowserRouter inside App.js and I also changed the way it all renders after getting the user that is logged in. Like this:

```
render () {
    let {loading } = this.state;
    if (loading) {
        return <h1>Loading</h1>;
    } else {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div>
                    <Navigation />
                    <div className="container">
                        <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage} />
                        <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />   
                    </div>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}
```

Now, the app stays loading until it has the user data, and after getting it, it renders everything else while also being able to navigate the app trough the Links.

It looks like the individual Routes can't be set after BrowserRouter is already in the DOM, or something like that, which I did not know.